# How to list folders in bash without the trailing /

Tags: linux, bash, path

I know

```
ls -d */
```

lists all folder in current directory as `dir1/ dir2/ dir3/`.

Is there the possibility in a bash script to show folders as `dir1 dir2 dir3`?

Comment: That sounds as if you want to parse the output of `ls`... which is in general [a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). What do you want to achieve in your script? I'd bet, there'll be a better way to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm curious as well. Why do you need this?

Comment: For a script that can discriminate folders from normal files..

Comment: `ls` should really only be used in interactive terminal sessions to look at the contents. If you're scripting and you need to do things to files or directories, use `find` with `-type f` or `-type d`, or iterate over `*`. For example `for foo in *; do …; done`. You can then use `if [[ -f "$foo" ]]` and `if [[ -d "$foo" ]]` to check if it's a file or directory, respectively. See also [the XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) – generally it's better to show the script you have and tell us what you *really* need to achieve. That way you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get only directories but omit the slash:

```
ls -d */ | sed 's#/##'
```

Or you'll have to use something like `find . -type d -maxdepth 1` (but this introduces `./` prefixing)

Comment: Tried it, it just lists every file and folder like simple ls..

Comment: Oh, you only want to list directories? That wasn't clear from your original question. I don't think `ls` dan do that out of the box. `ls -d */ | sed 's#/##'` does the trick or you'll have to use something like `find . -type d -maxdepth 1` (but this introduces './' prefixing).

Comment: ls -d */ | sed 's#/##'
Is perfect! Tanks!

Comment: I'm using MinTTY, and not sure why this doesn't work... I always get the slashes.

`COMPUTER+UserName@Computer MINGW64 /c/testbed`
`$ ls -d */ | sed 's#/##'`
New folder (2)/ 

New folder (3)/ 

New folder/

Comment: instead of `sed 's#/##'` just use `tr -d'/'`. But again, piping `ls` output will fail if folder names contain new lines https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425

Answer (score 7):

With `find` (this will also get rid of the `./` or `/path/to/` that would normally be prepended while using `find`):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

The above command will include `.` and also dotfiles (which would normally be hidden). To avoid all directories beginning with a dot (at least with GNU find):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.*' -printf '%f\n'
```

If you want to see hidden directories, but don't want `.`, you can use (again, only tested on GNU find, YMMV with other versions of find):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

Pure `bash`:

```
for f in */; do echo "${f%/}"; done
```

The following is a bit of a cheat, since it actually replaces the `/` with a blank space (so not really useful in scripts, but if all you want is slightly prettier output you might like it):

```
printf '%s\b \n' */
```

Alternatively, you can use `zsh` instead of `bash` and take advantage of its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-globbing_002c-qualifiers):

```
ls -d *(/)
```

Comment: With your `find` command, you will also find `./`, which is not in `ls -d */`

Comment: @Bernhard good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ls -d */ | awk -F/ '{print$1}'
```

it pipes the ls output to awk and tells it to consider the / as field delimiter, and to print the first field only

Answer (score 1):

Parsing output of `ls` is really a bad idea because the output format of `ls` is not guaranteed.

Here is a solution which does not need ls and thus does not depend on `ls` output formatting:

```
echo */ | sed s#/##g
```

Unfortunately the code above will not work correctly with directory names containing spaces. Because of this it is better to separate the list items by newlines or NULL characters. It is not easy to separate the arguments by something else than space without iterating them in a shell cycle.

Solution utilizing `/` to identify where newline should be put:

```
echo -n */ | sed 's#/ \?#\n#g'
```

Solution which utilizes changed parameter expansion separator:

```
nsplit() { IFS=$'\n' ; echo "$*" | sed 's#/$##' ; } ; nsplit */
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple combination with `dirname`

```sh
touch dir{1..3}
ls -d ./dir*
# ./dir1  ./dir2  ./dir3
```

```sh
ls -d ./dir* | xargs -I {} basename {}
# dir1
# dir2
# dir3
```